# update TextBox text format on LostFocus - WinRT

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I am developing an Windows Store app using C# and XAML and am working on a user input page. I use an `IValueConverter` that converts my bound data into currency formatted `string` instead of just showing a decimal.

When the user navigates to the page, the converter works fine and the `TextBox` text shows up with a currency format. However, when the user changes the `TextBox.Text` value and then the `TextBox` loses focus, the converter does not change it into a nice currency format again, it just stays formatted as it was entered by the user.

As far as I can tell, there is no `StringFormat` to use like in `WPF`, so how do I get the `TextBox` to display the currency format again after the user edits the value?

My converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            return ((decimal)value).ToString();
        return String.Format((string)parameter, (decimal)value);
    }

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        decimal decVal = 0M;
        decimal.TryParse((string)value, out decVal);
        return decVal;
    }
```

My XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="InputGrid">
    ...
    <Border>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyValue, ConverterParameter='{}{0:c}', Converter={StaticResource DecimalValueConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
    </Border>
    ....
</Grid>
```

`InputGrid.DataContext = MyValueClassInstance` set in the code-behind

Comment: Where is `MyValue` defined?  Are you using MVVM?

Comment: @DJBurb MyValue is defined in the `DataContext` of the `Grid` that holds my `TextBox`. The data binding seems to be working correctly, as my backend properties are getting properly updated.

Comment: Right, but are your backend properties implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @DJBurb Yes, they are. I'll double check to make sure there is not anything "weird" with WinRT-XAML and INotifyPropertyChanged, but as far as I can tell, it is working correctly.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the Grid in xaml?

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ConverterParameter='{}{0:c}', Converter={StaticResource DecimalValueConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: unfortunately, there is no `UpdateSourceTrigger` either :(

Answer (score 0):

Does your converter work both ways? I suspect that if it doesn't - the TwoWay binding gets broken.

Comment: I just added the `CovertBack` portion in my post... as far as I can tell, it is working fine.